# Width transition on a absolute positioned unordered list

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I want to animate the width of a unordered list. The width is determined whether the texts associated with a icon (in the fiddle represented by some characters) is displayed or not. Basically if the spans are shown the width of the menu is increased - i want to animate this action.

To expand the menu press the first button in the list. [This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nm43g6e/).

Here is a small extract from the jsFiddle -

```
<ul class="nav main-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="btnExpandNav">
             <i class="fa fa-sliders">A</i>
              <span>SEARCH</span>
        </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my css

```
ul
{
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-transition: width 1600ms ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1600ms ease;
    -ms-transition: width 1600ms ease;
    -o-transition: width 1600ms ease;
    transition: width 1600ms ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a time span parameter to the `show()` function.
Like `show(1000)`.

**Here is a snippet**

```js
var isNavExpanded = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  //nothing

  initializeAppUIComponents();
});

function initializeAppUIComponents() {
  navMenuChangeStateHandler(false);

  $('#btnExpandNav').click(function() {
    navMenuChangeStateHandler();
    setSubMenuItems();
  });
}

function navMenuChangeStateHandler(specificState) {
  if (specificState != null)
    isNavExpanded = !specificState;

  if (isNavExpanded)
    $('#mainNavCol > .main-menu > li > a > span').hide();
  else {
    $('#mainNavCol > .main-menu > li > a > span').show(1000);
  }

  isNavExpanded = !isNavExpanded;
}
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainNavCol">
  <ul class="nav main-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="btnExpandNav"><i class="fa fa-sliders">A</i><span class="magictime slideLeftRetourn">SEARCH</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders">B</i><span class="magictime slideLeftRetourn">Supply chain</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear">C</i><span class="magictime slideLeftRetourn">Warehouse</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart">D</i><span class="magictime slideLeftRetourn">Shipment</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's kind of in the right direction. My concern now is getting rid of the extra animation added by jquery (the slide up/height animation)